# Dimension of Moduli Space of Bundles on Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I think I'm getting conflicting results for the dimension of the moduli space of rank $r$, degree $d$ stable vector bundles on a curve $X$ of genus $g$.  I'm happy to look only at the nice case of $r$ and $d$ coprime such that stable and semi-stable are equivalent.  One can prove that in this case, the moduli space $M_{g}(r,d)$ is a smooth, projective variety of (complex) dimension $r^{2}(g-1) + 1$ for $g \geq 2$.

The issue I'm having, comes from an alternative angle.  One can also consider representations of the fundamental group $\rho: \pi_{1}(X) \to G$, where $G$ is compact, connected Lie group.  We can the following set:

$R_{d} = \big\{(A_{1}, B_{1}, \ldots, A_{g}, B_{g}) \big| \prod A_{i}B_{i}A_{i}^{-1}B_{i}^{-1} = e^{-2\pi i d/r} I \big\} \subseteq G^{2g},$

where of course the $A_{i},B_{i}$ are the images of the generators $a_{i},b_{i}$ of the fundamental group.  I think it's true that

$M_{g}(r,d) \simeq R_{d}/ U(r),$

where $U(n)$ acts on $R_{d}$ by conjugation.  For a general compact Lie group $G$, we have $2g\rm({dim}G)$ degrees of freedom in the $2g$ matrices, we subtract $\rm{dim}G$ corresponding to the constraint equation, as well as another $\rm{dim}G$ corresponding to conjugation symmetry.  All in all, we have a *real* dimension of $(\rm{dim}G)(2g-2)$.  The real dimension of $U(r)$ is of course $r^{2}$ which suggests that the real dimension of $M_{g}(r,d) = 2r^{2}(g-1)$.  This seems to disagree with the known formula by $\pm 2$.

Any idea what I am overlooking here?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each time you subtract $\dim G$ you're making an assumption that might not necessarily be true (in the first case about a certain map being a submersion or something, and in the second case about the conjugation action being suitably free). Let me stick to the case that $d = 0$. The commutator map from $G^{2g} \to G$ is not surjective for $G = U(r)$; it lands in $SU(r)$, and so you shouldn't subtract $\dim G$ here. Similarly, the center of $U(r)$ acts trivially by conjugation, so you also shouldn't subtract $\dim G$ here.

Comment: Ah, fantastic; I hadn't thought of that.  Thanks.  So my idea would go through correctly I believe in the case $G=\rm{SU}(r)$.  However for $G=\rm{U}(r)$, I notice that the result works perfectly if I subtract the dimension of $\rm{SU}(r)$ twice instead.  I guess this is just because the commutator map lands in $\rm{SU}(r)$ (like you said) and the elements of $\rm{SU}(r)$ are the only elements in the unitary group which act non-trivially by conjugation?

Comment: No, for conjugation the point is that the elements of the center act trivially, so the conjugation action factors through the projective unitary group, which has one lower dimension.